# undefined variable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

So how do I fix this?  It gives me:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: products
>   [APP/View/Categories/category_filter.ctp, line 10] Warning (2):
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   [APP/View/Categories/category_filter.ctp, line 10]

```
<? if (!empty($categories)) { ?> 

<? foreach($categories as $row): ?>
<h1>Category: <?= $row['Category']['category'] ?></h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Category</th>   
<th>Thumbnails</th>
    </tr>  
    <? foreach($products as $row): ?>
    <tr><<td>
        <?=$row['Product']['name']?>   
   </td><td>
        <?=$row['Product']['description']?>
   </td><td>
        <?=$row['Product']['price']?>   
   </td><td>
        <?=$row['Product']['category_id']?> 
   </td><td>
    <?
    if(!empty($row['Picture'])){
    ?> 
    <?= $this->Html->image('/img/'. $row['Picture'][0]['filename'], array('width'=>'50', 'alt'=>$row['Picture'][0]['title'])); ?>
            <p><?= $row['Picture'][0]['description']; ?></p>
     <? } ?>               
     </td><tr>

  <? endforeach; ?>
  <? endforeach; ?>


 </table>

 <? } ?>
```

In the controller

```
function category_filter($category_id) {
        $this->set('categories',$this->Category->findAllById($category_id));
    }
```

Comment: you did not set the products variable in your controller's method.

Comment: Can you show me the correct way of doing it?  I tried it but got a fatal error.

Comment: What is your table structure and Product and Category Model? Kindly explain here so that I can give you a better solution.

Comment: categories with | id | category |

Comment: products is | id | name | description | category_id |

Comment: Product model: var $belongsTo = 'Category';

Comment: Category model: var $hasMany = 'Product';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by making a `Category Model class`.

```
//app/Model/Category.php
class Category extends AppModel
{
   public $name = 'Category';
   public $useTable = 'categories';    
   public $primaryKey = 'id';
   public $hasMany = array('Products' => array('className' => 'Product',
                                           'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
                                           ));    
}

//app/Model/Product.php
class Product extends AppModel
{
  public $name = 'Product';
  public $useTable = 'products';    
  public $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

In your controller:

```
function category_filter($category_id) {
    $this->set('category_details',$this->Category->findById($category_id));
}
```

In your view:

```
<h1>Category: <?php echo $category_details['Category']['category'] ?></h1>

<table>
<tr>
     <th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Category</th>   
<th>Thumbnails</th>
</tr>  
<?php if(!empty($category_details['Products'])): foreach($category_details['Products'] as $row): ?>
<tr><td>
    <?php echo $row['Product']['name']?>
```

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/'. $row['Picture'][0]['filename'], array('width'=>'50', 'alt'=>$row['Picture'][0]['title'])); ?>
        <p><?php echo $row['Picture'][0]['description']; ?></p>
 <?php } ?>               
 </td><tr>
<?php endforeach;endif; ?>
```

As I do not much aware about your `Picture Model`. Kindly do the association for that model also in your Product model.

Comment: Picture model: var $belongsTo = array('Product'); Product mode: var $hasMany = array('Picture');

Comment: picture table has the product_id foreign key

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function category_filter($category_id) {
    $this->set('categories',$this->Category->findAllById($category_id));
    $products=$this->Product->find('all');
   $this->set(compact('products'));
    }   
?>
```

set your product variable